# combine two redux reducers

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a use case like this:

eventListReducer: will get a list of events based on date range

eventDetailReducer: will get the event details based on one event id

I know how to do the two above, my question:
When my page loads initially, I will get a list of events based on default date range and load the first event details, I can certainly create an 
EventListAndDetailReducer to duplicate eventListReducer and eventDetailReducer. Is there any better way I can reuse the logic?

What I want to achieve is to have another action, that will first call getEvents and update the eventLists state, and then grab the first event and call setEvent and update the eventDetail state.

This is my eventDetailReducer:

```
const initialState = {
    eventDetails: "",
}

const eventReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_EVENT":
            state = {
                ...state,
                eventDetails: action.payload
        };

        break;
    }

    return state;
}

export default eventReducer;
```

This is my eventsReducer:

```
const initialState = {
    eventsList: [],
}

//getEventsReducer
const getEventsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_EVENTS":
            state = {
                ...state,
                eventList: ["Joe", "Tom", "Marry"] //assuming this from some other endpoint
            };
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default getEventsReducer;
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Added some code to illustrate my use case

Answer (score 0):

What about using `EventListAndDetailReducer`?

```
const initialState = {
  eventsList: [],
  eventDetails: ""
}

export function eventListAndDetailReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_EVENTS:
      return {...state, eventList: eventsReducer(state.eventsList, action)}
    case "SET_EVENT":
      return {...state, eventDetails: eventDetailsReducer(state.eventDetails, action)}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and then somewhen start using `combineReducers`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the `eventDetails` reducer also update on the `GET_EVENTS` action?

```
const eventReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_EVENT":
            state = {
                ...state,
                eventDetails: action.payload
        };
        break;
        case "GET_EVENTS":
            state = {
                ...state,
                eventDetails: action.payload[0] // assuming payload is an array
        };
        break;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Remember, all reducers receive all actions, so it does not need to be a 1-1 mapping.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you question is that you want another action to do both actions sequentially and be dependent on each. I assume you have some middle ware such as `redux-thunk` that allows actions to be more than plaIn functions!

```
export function combinedAction() {
 return (dispatch, getState) => {

  // Write fetch() request to get events list from anywhere.
  // Following should be within .then() if you're using fetch. 
  // Here events are just hardcoded in reducer! 

  dispatch(return { type: GET_EVENTS, payload: events }).then( () => {
     let event = getState().eventsList[0]
     dispatch(return { type: SET_EVENT, payload: event })
  })

 };
}
```

This will fire up `GET_EVENTS` action first and it'll set events array in `state.eventsList`. Then next action just uses this `state` information to dispatch next action `SET_EVENT`. Refer here to learn about chaining actions. [How to chain async actions?](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1676)